# In a Highcharts heatmap is it possible for a data point to be ignored for the color scale?

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

I'm trying to create a heatmap where the first column is a set of absolute values and the subsequent columns are the percent change from that first column.

This unfortunately causes the color and scale of the heatmap to be skewed.  What I'm hoping to do is find some property that I can set that will cause values to not be used to skew the min/max.

http://jsfiddle.net/hasaki/6rkk66p1/3/

Based on another question, I thought if I specify the color it wouldn't skew the axis, but my fiddle shows otherwise.

Here is how I'm currently trying to code the data, which results in the skewed min/max and skewed color scale:

```
series: [{
  data: [
    {x: 0, y: 0, value: 120, color: '#FFFFFF'}, 
    {x: 0, y: 1, value: 130, color: '#FFFFFF'},
    {x: 1, y: 0, value: 0.435},
    {x: 1, y: 1, value: 0.775},
    {x: 2, y: 1, value: 80}, // just to show they are in the middle of the range
    {x: 2, y: 1, value: 15},
  ],
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    formatter: function() { 
      return `${Math.round(this.point.value * 10) / 10} ${this.point.x ? '%' : ''}`; 
    }
}]
```

This heatmap is part of a larger charting application, where I won't necessarily know the domain of values could be too different for a min/max to be determined ahead of time. I'd prefer to let highcharts figure out the min/max and colors on most of the cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prepare your data like this before passing it to the chart constructor:

```
data: (function() {

      data.forEach(function(p) {
        if (p.x > 0) {
          var basePoint = data.find((p_) => p_.x === 0 && p_.y === p.y);
          p.originalValue = p.value;
          p.value = p.value * basePoint.value;
        }

      });
            return data;

    })()
```

I computed the actual value for every point and use it as a `value` property.  I saved the percentage in `percentValue` property to use it later in `dataLabels.formatter` (it should be used analogically in tooltip formatter).

**Live working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/vbgxscgt/

Now all the points are in the same scale and color axis works properly.

Comment: That would do it! I need to flip it around, as its possible the base value isn't in the range of the values I want the color scale against, but this exposes a fact I wasn't aware of, that the point passed in to the series is available in the formatters.